# Adding inline styles to react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Currently I'm using react.js and I'm trying to get two div's to be side by side.
Currently I'm trying to

```
<div id="sidebar" style = "display:inline-block;" >
  <script src="build/sidebar.js"></script>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="display: inline-block; width: 20%; height: 50%; "></div>
```

with sidebar.js as the where react is stored. This unfortunately doesnt work however as it just moves map-canvas to the side while sidebar isn't to the left of it; its on top. I've tried many various combinations w/ float as well and none of them seem to work

Another option is to edit the sidebar.js code where I currently have

```
return <div>
  <input type="text" value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type here" />
  <ul>
    { libraries.map(function(l){
      return <li>{l.name} </li>
    }) }
  </ul>
</div>;
```

in which I try doing `return <div style ="display: inline-block;">`
However, in this case the generated html doesnt show up at all. I'm perplex to what I should try but react seems like it doesnt want to play nice with other div elements.

Answer (score 27):

That's because in React, the `style` prop [takes an object instead of a semicolon-separated string](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html).

```
<div id="sidebar" style={{display : 'inline-block'}} >
  <script src="build/sidebar.js"></script>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas" style={{display: 'inline-block', width: '20%', height: '50%'}}>
</div>
```

Edit:

So this:

```
return <div style="display: inline-block;">
```

Would become this:

```
return <div style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt make this clear, the first block of code is in the html document while the 2nd block of code is the actual JSX not the converted javascript. Is the inline style for JSX the same as with an object instead of semicolon separated string?

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully make it a bit more clear.  If I understand correctly, that is the line you were trying to add an inline style on.

Comment: @MichaelParker - works well for me https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/inline-css-styles-hover

Answer (score 1):

```
const styles = {
  container: {
   backgroundColor: '#ff9900',
   ...
   ...
   textAlign: 'center'
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container" style={styles.container}>
      // your other codes here...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's usually a good practice to explain what the code does and how it answers the question, so that other users can also benefit from it.