# How to set a few items in a line

Tags: html, css, reactjs

There a few HTML elements that I want to put in a line. This is the code I have used.

```html
 <input type = "text" className="search" placeholder="Search"></input>
              
                <a href="/">
                <img src="logo.svg"></img>
                <h3>NameOfTheWebsite</h3>
                </a>
            
          
              <a href = "#">SignIn</a>
              <a href = "#">SignOut</a>
```

But the output for this code is like this.

[image: Output of the above code]

I want to put those elements in the same line and the logo should be top of the website name. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding inline styles to react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972552/adding-inline-styles-to-react)

Answer (score 1):

FlexBox is a really useful thing in such situations. In the following snippet, I have used some flexboxes just to get you familiar with it. But this is something that you should definitely master and use in your CSS layouts. MDN Web docs have [a really great tutorial for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
.home-page{
  display:flex;
  margin:15px;
}
.controls{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
.signing-buttons{
  display:flex;
}
.signing-buttons a{
  margin:5px;
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:4px;
}
```

```html
<a class="home-page" href="/">
  
  <h3>NameOfTheWebsite</h3>
  <img src="logo.svg"></img>
</a>
<div class="controls">
  <input type = "text" className="search" placeholder="Search"></input>
  <div class="signing-buttons">
    <a href = "#">SignIn</a>
    <a href = "#">SignOut</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can use flexbox to achieve this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). Just a minimalistic example to illustrate my point is shown below. You can control how much space each item will occupy and a lot of other things.

```css
.row {
display:flex;
}

.search {
flex:1;
border:1px solid black
}
.name {
flex:1;
border:1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
<div class='search'>Search Box</div>
<div class = 'name'>Name</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>Next line</>
```