# How to add styles to a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add styles to my component, but I don't see any result. What do I do wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
// import * as styles from '../styles';

export default function App({title}) {
  return (
    <div styles={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{title}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: use `style`, not `styles`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding inline styles to react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972552/adding-inline-styles-to-react)